# Determining if std::sort(begin, end) modified the range

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, std

What is the most elegant way to determine if a call to `std::sort(begin, end)` actually modified the range?

Here are my two ideas:

**(a) check if already sorted O(n):**

```
if (already_sorted(begin, end)) { return false; }
std::sort(begin, end);
return true;
```

**(b) track changes in comparator (is this safe?):**

```
bool modified = false;
std::sort(begin, end, [&modified](T a, T b){ modified |= a<b; return a<b; });
return modified;
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't think (b) is safe:  the algorithm could test `comp(b, a)` instead of `comp(a, b)` and swap if the result is `false`.

Comment: I think a better question is why you need to know if the range is already sorted--perhaps you should pick a sorting algorithm that handles already-sorted ranges in a "safe" manner, so you don't have to care if the range is sorted?

Comment: @Jeff: my application has a process that's likely to produce a sorted range. In the case that it isn't, a few steps need to be repeated.

Comment: The efficiency of (a) will depend on whether in your context the data usually is already sorted.  If it usually is sorted then you've done a O(N) operation and saved yourself a O(N log N).  However, if the data mostly isn't already sorted then you're constanty adding a O(N) to the O(N log N) you're always doing anyway.  In this instance it'd probably just be most efficient to just sort without checking.  Particularly since I think std::sort is O(N) anway if the data is already sorted....

Comment: (b) is certainly wrong for typical pivot-based sorting method. In a pre-sorted range they'd pick the middle element as a pivot, and 50% of the elements would be smaller than the pivot. So, for a pre-sorted container of 3 or more elements, at least one comparison against the pivot would set `modified`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you iterate through the structure from "begin" to "end", you can't know if it is already sorted, so the best you can do it is in O(n).

I would go for the first choice, the already_sorted one.

Comment: Note: the typical implementation of `is_sorted(FwdIt begin, FwdIt end)` is `return std::adjacent_find(begin, end, std::greater<value_type>()) == end;`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do this any better than O(n) checking if the array came back in a different order than which it started.  Hijacking the comparator to see if things are out if order isn't guaranteed to work, since in theory the sort function can do whatever comparisons it likes without necessarily moving anything.  Moreover, tracking whether any swaps were performed doesn't necessarily tell you if the order changed, since the sort could also move things around and restore them to the same order at the end of the sort (think heapsort, for example).

Answer (score 1):

Do you consider a range modified if two equal values were exchanged? In that case the already_sorted variant won't work.

Otherwise it should be the fastest way.

Comment: Hmm... I think using `std::stable_sort` would clear up this case.

Answer (score 1):

If the objects being sorted are of class type, you could introduce a subobject with an `operator =` overload that would be called by `std::swap`. However, that could in theory still allow false positives, if objects were swapped and then swapped back.

Probably you should stick with `already_sorted` until you're sure that it is taking a significant amount of the total execution time.